# I want to Hide Select tag which is inside tr with no class and td with class

Tags: jquery

in below tr and td ar coming dynamically from a function-

```
<table class="adm-detail-content-table edit-table" id="edit1_edit_table">
   <tr>
    <td class="adm-detail-content-cell-l" width="40%">&nbsp;Type:</td>
        <td class="adm-detail-content-cell-r" width="60%">
            <select name="UF_TYPE">
                <option value="">Select type</option>
                <option value="26" selected="">Complaint</option>
                <option value="27">Request</option>
                <option value="28">Query</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: try `$('table').find('select').hide()`

Comment: Please show us your code, what have you tried and it's not working?

Comment: please clear out your requirement, you are misguiding all of us.

Comment: i am not able to give complete code as there is character limit to text box of comment

Comment: @Sanj  it's not about  full html. just add two three more tr's in your code and please clear out your requirement correctly.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will hide each `tr` which have `select` as a children:-

```
$('table tr').each(function(){
 if($(this).find('select[name="UF_MODE"]').length || $(this).find('select[name="UF_TYPE"]').length){
   $(this).hide();
 };
});
```

Example:-

```js
$('table tr').each(function(){
 if($(this).find('select[name="UF_MODE"]').length || $(this).find('select[name="UF_TYPE"]').length){
   $(this).hide();
 };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="adm-detail-content-table edit-table" id="edit1_edit_table">
   <tr>
    <td class="adm-detail-content-cell-l" width="40%">&nbsp;Type:</td>
        <td class="adm-detail-content-cell-r" width="60%">
            <select name="UF_MODE">
                <option value="">Select type</option>
                <option value="26" selected="">Complaint</option>
                <option value="27">Request</option>
                <option value="28">Query</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="adm-detail-content-cell-l" width="40%">&nbsp;Type:</td>
        <td class="adm-detail-content-cell-r" width="60%">
            <select name="UF_TYPE">
                <option value="">Select type</option>
                <option value="26" selected="">Complaint</option>
                <option value="27">Request</option>
                <option value="28">Query</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="adm-detail-content-cell-l" width="40%">&nbsp;Type:</td>
        <td class="adm-detail-content-cell-r" width="60%">
            <select name="UN_TYPE">
                <option value="">Select type</option>
                <option value="26" selected="">Complaint</option>
                <option value="27">Request</option>
                <option value="28">Query</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: i want to hide complete row but there are multiple tr in table

Comment: one more thing select tag repeats in each tr with diffrent name and name starts with prefix i.e. UF_MODE,UF_TYPE,UF_DATE etc.

Comment: i want to hide complete row

Comment: one issue facing it is hiding all row but i want to hide only tr which has select tag with name UF_MODE,UF_TYPE etc.

Comment: @Sanj  i have edited code according to your requirement.YOU CAN CHECK NOW.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function(){
$('.adm-detail-content-cell-r select').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="adm-detail-content-table edit-table" id="edit1_edit_table">
   <tr>
    <td class="adm-detail-content-cell-l" width="40%">&nbsp;Type:</td>
        <td class="adm-detail-content-cell-r" width="60%">
            <select name="UF_TYPE">
                <option value="">Select type</option>
                <option value="26" selected="">Complaint</option>
                <option value="27">Request</option>
                <option value="28">Query</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

use this in case you want to hide complete row :

```
   $(function(){
      $('tr:first-child').hide();
   });
```

```js
$(function(){
$('tr:first-child').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="adm-detail-content-table edit-table" id="edit1_edit_table">
   <tr>
    <td class="adm-detail-content-cell-l" width="40%">&nbsp;Type:</td>
        <td class="adm-detail-content-cell-r" width="60%">
            <select name="UF_TYPE">
                <option value="">Select type</option>
                <option value="26" selected="">Complaint</option>
                <option value="27">Request</option>
                <option value="28">Query</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: i want to hide complete row i.e. tr

Comment: @sanj i have updated my answer, in case you want to hide whole row use second one.

Comment: i want to hide tr

Comment: @sanj  $(function(){
      $('tr:first-child').hide();
   }); is hiding tr only

Comment: actually there are multiple tr in table that's why i cant use second answer

Comment: @sanj you want to hide all of them? this solution will hide the first one which consist of select. Please let us know if there are tr above it?

Comment: in table there are multiple tr inside each tr  there is select tag with diffrent name starts with prefix UF_   i.e. UF_MODE,UF_TYPE,UF_DATE etc. so i want to hide all row tr

Answer (score 0):

Jquery give you [`selector`](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) and [`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) function for the task. You just need to select the element by using jquery `selector` which you want to hide and then apply `hide()` function for hiding. The `hide()` function will display block that element, also you can remove it by using jquery [`remove()`](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) function.

```js
$('.adm-detail-content-table tr td.adm-detail-content-cell-r select').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="adm-detail-content-table edit-table" id="edit1_edit_table">
  <tr>
    <td class="adm-detail-content-cell-l" width="40%">&nbsp;Type:</td>
    <td class="adm-detail-content-cell-r" width="60%">
      <select name="UF_TYPE">
                <option value="">Select type</option>
                <option value="26" selected="">Complaint</option>
                <option value="27">Request</option>
                <option value="28">Query</option>
            </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```